# Can I push a batch of token_id using the Firebase Cloud Messaging console?

Tags: batch-file, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, bulk

I want to send push notifications tospecific users. I cannot use FCM native targeting options because we don't (and won't) use Google Analytics.

Can I push a batch of token_ids using the Firebase Cloud Messaging console ? The interface is interesting because it doesn't require any technical intervention from IT teams.
Of course, the batch will only include specific users I'd need to target.

How can I upload such a batch by myself only using the console ?
Thanks a lot !

I tried to find any documentation about this, but found nothing.
My developers and I didn't find how to upload batchs on FCM console (we can create a message, targeting is unavailable (since we don't user Google Analytics) and no field seems to be dealing with any batch capability.

Comment: Please take a look at the description for the [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) tag, and ensure that your question relates to one or more commands written within an executable file, _(with a `.BAT` or `.CMD` file extension)_, on Windows, DOS, or OS/2. If it does not, please delete that tag, or replace it with something more suitable. There is an [Edit] link just below your question body to use for such purposes.